# Clear Interval doesn't work in VUE

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am trying to build a Pomodoro Timer using VUE.js, below is the relevant code snippet that I had problems on. So the problem is that the clearInterval Method doesn't seem to work here.

```
   data: {
        workTimeInMin: 1,
        breakTimeInMin: 1,
        timeRemainInMillisecond: 0,
        timerOn: false,
        rest: false
      },

      methods: {
        startOrStopTheTimer: function() {
          var self = this;
          var interval;
          if (this.timerOn){
            this.timerOn = !this.timerOn;
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            console.log("clearInterval");
          }else {
            this.timerOn = !this.timerOn;
            interval = setInterval(function(){
            console.log("123");
            if (self.timeRemainInMillisecond <= 0) {
              console.log("1");
              self.rest = !self.rest;
              if (self.rest) {
                self.timeRemainInMillisecond = self.restTimeInMin*60*1000;
              }else {
                self.timeRemainInMillisecond = self.workTimeInMin*60*1000;
              }
            }
              this.timeRemainInMillisecond = this.timeRemainInMillisecond-1000
            }, 1000);
          }
        },
```

[You can find a live demo here.](https://codepen.io/ge524119574/full/EXVbWB/)

In the page, when I click start an set Interval method is called. Then I clicked the stop, it is supposed to clear the interval, however it doesn't seem to work as I intend it to. You can inspect the console and easily find the "123" keeps popping up which indicates that the interval is not cleared.

After searching a while in the StackOverFlow, I found that if I define the variable `interval` to in the global context it will work as I intend it. But I wish to know why it is so.

Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You realize that `var interval;` created new variable with value `undefined`?

Comment: use window.interval to set the value globally

Comment: @dfsq I am aware of that. Then the interval should be set to `var interval = setInterval` in the else part of the for loop. So I am wondering why I can't use `clearInterval` here.

Comment: your `interval` variable is scoped to the method, so you get a new one every time the method runs.  I would scope it to the component -- put it in the `data` block -- rather than polluting `window` with globals.  (This would also eliminate the need for your `timerOn` variable.)

Comment: I found that this.interval was setting it to the object, and not the actual ID in a nodejs environment. so I had to run `clearInterval(this.interval._id)`

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that `var interval` is a declared new every time the function is called. So the variable that holds a reference to your interval is not accessible.

Just use `this.interval` and the variable will added to the data-section of your component under the hood.

You can also just use this mixin (plugin) / have a look how it works there:
[Vue interval mixin](https://github.com/reinerBa/Vue-Interval)

Comment: This worked for me in Dec 2019 - I didn't declare interval in my `data() { }` section, but instead just assigned my interval to this.interval. Adding it to data stopped it from working.

Answer (score 6):

You can clear setInterval and clearinterval. here is sample code please modify according to your need

```
if (val && !this.t) {
    this.t = setInterval(() => {
        location.reload()
    }, 10 * 1000)
} else {
    clearInterval(this.t)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I arrived at this page because Vue still seems to handle setInterval in the strange way as described by the OP. I tried all the fixes above and found only two options work:

- Global scope the interval variable (as mentioned above and less than an ideal workaround)
- Use Vuex to store the timer and handle it the usual Vuex way.

I was happy to find that using Vuex bypasses the problem, since I'm using Vuex anyway. It doesn't shed light on why this issue exists, but it does give us a way to move forward with little sacrifices made.

So just declare the variable in the Vuex state, use mutations to start and stop the timer and all works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

This works like a charm:

```js
data () {
    return {
        polling: null
    }
},
methods: {
    pollData () {
        this.polling = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('fired...')
        }, 3000)
    }
},
beforeDestroy () {
    clearInterval(this.polling)
},
created () {
    this.pollData()
}
```

Comment: Indeed, clearing the interval function stored in `data` rather than in methods makes it work

Comment: in my case, ```this.polling``` has increased value each time.